# get the name of methods as they execute in a specific thread

Tags: java, trace

In my Java application, I wish to get the name (and actual runtime class) of different methods as they execute in a specific thread. Its different then getting a regular stack trace. Its like I am on observer looking at the execution of my program and see the names of different methods appear as they are run.

One (naive and practically infeasible) way is to put a print message at the beginning of each method to print its name (class, line number, etc.). I can use the exception trace to get all the relevant info to print, BUT I would have to add at least one line to the beginning of each method which is not very elegant. Furthermore, if I miss/forget to add a line at the beginning of any method, that method name would not be displayed. Also, this strategy is not future-proof. Is there any instrumentation/other technique that will help me accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Aspect Oriented Programmation and all of the frameworks implementing it.

If you are using spring you can have a look at the simple trace interceptor that will do exactly what you want : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/SimpleTraceInterceptor.html

Comment: I thought about AOP (was taught in graduate school), but it is too cumbersome and requires me to interject code which is more work than adding a line at the beginning of each method. I was not aware about springsource. I am currently checking out what this is.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from AOP and the Spring Listener mentioned in the other answer below, you could use maybe some trickier code generation framework such as ASM or CGLib. You'd be writing code to rewrite each of your classes at runtime and append these print instructions at the beginning of your methods. But that requires deeper knowledge of bytecode.